# SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY LIMIT not working

Tags: mysql, jsp

i wanted to display the table values when the user selecting range. The user input saving using String range=request.getParameter();
I put this value in to this mysql query

```
"SELECT * FROM user_info ORDER BY user_id LIMIT '"+range+"',10";
```

but it displays a syntax error msg. some problem in '"+range+"' syntax.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1',10' at line 1  .

Comment: Don't put the first value into single quotes. Those are numbers, not strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using quotes for range. So query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM user_info ORDER BY user_id LIMIT '1',10
```

which is wrong.

Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM user_info ORDER BY user_id LIMIT "+range+",10";
```